# Probability of the occurrence of a random event x in a population X where n = $\infty$?

Tags: probability, limits

Given a random event x from a discrete population X where the population $n=\infty$, and the population is uniformly distributed, what is P(x)?

My intuition is that it is infinitesimal, because as $lim_{n\to\infty}$, $ lim_{p\to0}$

Comment: Related (and there are many other similar postings on this site): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880140/is-getting-a-random-integer-even-possible

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite answer my question, and using search on the site didn't lead me anywhere useful for this particular inquiry.

Comment: In this context "infinitesimal" is the right intuition, but it's not precise. There is no uniform probability distribution on an infinite set.

Comment: Sorry but I'm just not seeing the correlation -- why is there no uniform probability on an infinite set?

Answer (score 2):

There is no uniform discrete probability distribution on an infinite set $X$, for suppose $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is the probability mass function for such a distribution. Then $f$ should satisfy 
$$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=1$$
and
$$(\forall x,y\in X)(f(x)=f(y))$$
Pick $x_0\in X$. Then by the second requirement, for all $x\in X$ we have $f(x)=f(x_0)$. Then by the first requirement,
$$\sum_{x\in X} f(x_0)=1$$
But this is impossible to satisfy. For if $f(x_0)=0$, then the sum comes out to zero; but if $f(x_0)\neq 0$, then the sum doesn't converge to a finite value.